# What are the guidelines for call signs for aircraft dealing with US ATC?

Tags: faa-regulations, radio-communications, call-sign

Suppose a general aviation aircraft is operating VFR under part 91. When they call ATC they'd normally use their tail number as the call sign. Something like "November 1-2-3 Foxtrot Uniform." What if they called up as "little piggy 27?" Are there guidelines or regulations about this? Does a custom call sign require anything or can you just make one up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [JO 7210.3Y](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/JO_7210.3Y.pdf), *Air Traffic Organisation Policy*, section 4-4-2 there are several requirements from both the FAA and FCC. The FAA requirements are (paraphrased from the JO):

- Comply with FCC regulations (remember that the FCC is responsible for radio communication technical regulations, not the FAA)
- Get FAA approval "to avoid possible duplication or conflict
  with air−ground call signs assigned on a national
  basis to other aircraft operators"

The FCC requirements are in [47 CFR 87.107](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr;rgn=div5;view=text;node=47%3A5.0.1.1.2;idno=47;cc=ecfr#se47.5.87_1107) (not 87.115 as the JO says):

> (a) *Aircraft station*. Identify by one of the following means:
>
> (1) Aircraft radio station call sign.
>
> (2) The type of aircraft followed by the characters of the
>   registration marking (“N” number) of the aircraft, omitting the prefix
>   letter “N.” When communication is initiated by a ground station, an
>   aircraft station may use the type of aircraft followed by the last
>   three characters of the registration marking. Notwithstanding any
>   other provision of this section, an aircraft being moved by
>   maintenance personnel from one location in an airport to another
>   location in that airport may be identified by a station identification
>   consisting of the name of the company owning or operating the
>   aircraft, followed by the word “Maintenance” and additional
>   alphanumeric characters of the licensee's choosing.
>
> (3) The FAA assigned radiotelephony designator of the aircraft
>   operating organization followed by the flight identification number.
>
> (4) An aircraft identification approved by the FAA for use by aircraft
>   stations participating in an organized flying activity of short
>   duration.

In other words, your call sign must be approved in advance by the FAA, otherwise you can't legally use it per FCC regulations. In reality, if you call up ATC as *Little Piggy 27* you'll either get a laugh and a "no, seriously?" or - in the worst case - you'll just annoy them.

There are also military call signs in use but I know nothing about them. I do remember being in the pattern while an Air National Guard aircraft out of Memphis, TN was doing touch and goes using the call sign Elvis 1. But I have no idea how that call sign was set up between the ANG and FAA.

Comment: I might as well add since you mentioned military callsigns, Civil Air Patrol (USAF Aux Not really a military organization) Aircraft callsigns are semi-permanent which go like: "CAP nnnn"

Answer (score 2):

Operator call signs are generally established with the FAA>
In addition, operators can establish local call signs with their ATC facility.
E.g. News Chopper 10.

The FAA has established aircraft types in call signs at well.

You can't just make up a call sign.

Comment: Do you have any references?

Comment: Here's one on local call signs: http://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/notice/final_n_jo_7210_878_use_of_aircraft_call_signs.pdf

Comment: http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/AIM_Basic_4-03-14.pdf P. 4-2-3

Comment: I think it would improve the quality of the answer to incorporate the references into the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

From ATC's point of view...

If a pilot calls up as "little piggy 27", the controller **may** respond **initially** with "little piggy 27".

When **ATC establishes** communication with a GA aircraft, they state the prefix "November" followed by the phonetic numbers/letters of the aircraft registration.

As a pilot, you could replace "November" with aircraft type, the model, or the manufacturer’s name, and ATC can respond in kind going forward.

[Info from [JO 7110.65](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf), 2−4−20. AIRCRAFT IDENTIFICATION]